# Sql Server left join not returning matching rows

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which already has a table joined and results are as expected. They match the 1st table

```
     SELECT 
        A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
        A.RH6002 as UAP, 
        A.RH6030 as ConsumoWeek01, 
        A.RH6031 as ConsumoWeek02,
        IC130M.LLBLT1 as Stock,
        0 as PecasPorCaixa
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
    LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M IC130M 
    ON A.RH6001 = IC130M.LLPPN AND
         IC130M.LLSTLC =
             CASE A.RH6002
                  WHEN 'UAP1' THEN 'M1'
                  WHEN 'UAP2' THEN 'M2'
                  WHEN 'UAP3' THEN 'M3'
                  WHEN 'UAP4' THEN 'M4'
                  WHEN 'UAP5' THEN 'M5'
                  WHEN 'UAP6' THEN 'M6'
                  WHEN 'UAPP' THEN 'PROTOS'
                  WHEN 'EXT' THEN 'EXTR'
                END     
    WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like 'FS%') 
    AND A.RH6030 <> 0
    ORDER BY Referencia DESC')
```

Which returns me 1361 rows.

Now I have another query

```
    SELECT 
        YDAUREP.AUD5CD AS Referencia,
        YDAUREP.AUQCON AS PecasPorCaixa
    FROM 
        AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDAUREP YDAUREP
    WHERE (YDAUREP.AUD5CD Like 'M%' 
    AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD Not Like '%P%') 
    AND (YDAUREP.AUA0NB>1) 
    AND (YDAUREP.AUG6ST='O')
    ORDER BY YDAUREP.AUD5CD'
```

Which returns 785 rows

I want to join both tables where all the rows on the 2nd table match the 1st table, basically it should return me 1361 rows.

I have to join both tables using column `Referencia`, problem is that it is unique value on 2nd table, while on the 1st table it is not and I think it's 'cause of this that it is not returning the expected rows.

Here is the query with both tables joined:

```
    SELECT 
        A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
        A.RH6002 as UAP, 
        A.RH6030 as ConsumoWeek01, 
        A.RH6031 as ConsumoWeek02,
        IC130M.LLBLT1 as Stock,
        YDAUREP.AUQCON AS PecasPorCaixa
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
    LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M IC130M 
    ON A.RH6001 = IC130M.LLPPN AND
         IC130M.LLSTLC =
             CASE A.RH6002
                  WHEN 'UAP1' THEN 'M1'
                  WHEN 'UAP2' THEN 'M2'
                  WHEN 'UAP3' THEN 'M3'
                  WHEN 'UAP4' THEN 'M4'
                  WHEN 'UAP5' THEN 'M5'
                  WHEN 'UAP6' THEN 'M6'
                  WHEN 'UAPP' THEN 'PROTOS'
                  WHEN 'EXT' THEN 'EXTR'
                END     
    LEFT JOIN AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDAUREP YDAUREP
    ON YDAUREP.AUD5CD = A.RH6001
    WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like 'FS%') 
    AND A.RH6030 <> 0
    AND (YDAUREP.AUD5CD Like 'M%' 
    AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD Not Like '%P%') 
    AND (YDAUREP.AUA0NB>1) 
    AND (YDAUREP.AUG6ST='O')
    ORDER BY Referencia DESC'
```

Either I'm doing something wrong or I don't know how to use joins anymore.

I'm doing a left join and the result returned is 579 rows, which means it returns me all the rows from 2nd table that match the 1st table and I thought a left join would do the opposite.

Either way, even if I use Right Join it returns me the same rows...

I'm not sure but the problem could be the extra where clauses I added.

How can I get my 1361 rows with just the data on the 2nd table that matches?

The rest can be `NULL`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing `YDAUREP` in your `WHERE` without handling `NULL`, turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`. Move that section to the `ON`:

```
SELECT A.RH6001 AS Referencia,
       A.RH6002 AS UAP,
       A.RH6030 AS ConsumoWeek01,
       A.RH6031 AS ConsumoWeek02,
       IC130M.LLBLT1 AS Stock,
       YDAUREP.AUQCON AS PecasPorCaixa
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
     LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M AS IC130M ON A.RH6001 = IC130M.LLPPN
                                               AND IC130M.LLSTLC = CASE A.RH6002
                                                                        WHEN 'UAP1' THEN 'M1'
                                                                        WHEN 'UAP2' THEN 'M2'
                                                                        WHEN 'UAP3' THEN 'M3'
                                                                        WHEN 'UAP4' THEN 'M4'
                                                                        WHEN 'UAP5' THEN 'M5'
                                                                        WHEN 'UAP6' THEN 'M6'
                                                                        WHEN 'UAPP' THEN 'PROTOS'
                                                                        WHEN 'EXT' THEN 'EXTR'
                                                                   END
     LEFT JOIN AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDAUREP AS YDAUREP ON YDAUREP.AUD5CD = A.RH6001
                                                AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD LIKE 'M%'
                                                AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD NOT LIKE '%P%'
                                                AND YDAUREP.AUA0NB > 1
                                                AND YDAUREP.AUG6ST = 'O'
WHERE A.RH6001 NOT LIKE 'FS%'
  AND A.RH6030 <> 0
ORDER BY Referencia DESC;
```

*I also removed the extra parenthesis, as they weren't needed.*

Comment: This is what i was looking for but it returns me some extra 100 rows

Comment: Then you have a many-to-one (or possibly many-to-many) relationship @Jackal. I can't help you there as I have no knowledge of your data.

Comment: that makes sense, however i have no control over the data returned since it's on a db2 linked server and these queries are actually open queries. I'll have to find a way to link both tables with unique value